# What type of data is this? Nominal, ordinal, interval, ratio

Tags: dataset, measurement

If you were to do a survey and ask, “how many people have lived in a town for less than 2 years, 2-9 years or greater than 9 years?” Would this be considered nominal, ordinal, interval or ratio?

Comment: I’m thinking ordinal data? Would you agree?

Answer (score 2):

It's ratio data, regrouped into an ordinal scale.  Think of it like rounding.  You're not really going to be able to use many of the ratio properties of the data, except in very specific (and somewhat contrived) circumstances, so for all intents and purposes the scale is now ordinal.

Such regrouping of data (and associated transformation of the level of measurement) happens all the time, especially with data considered to be continuous.  Even when rounding (say) floating point numbers, we are technically converting from an interval or ratio scale to an ordinal one -- but the ordinal data in such cases behaves so similarly to a genuine interval/ratio scale that people tend to ignore the distinction.

For example, you still know that anybody in the "greater than 9 years" group will have lived in a town at least four and a half times as long as anybody in the "less than 2 years" group, which is a ratio property.  Most of the ratio properties of your data have been wiped out though, by the conversion to a small number of irregularly-sized ordinal categories.